# Binary search function

Tags: python, python-2.x, sorting, binary-search

I have written this function to perform a binary search on an array, given begin/end indices and a value to look for in the supplied array:

```
def binarySearch(array, beginIndex, endIndex, value):
    while (beginIndex < endIndex):
        mid = (beginIndex + endIndex) / 2
        if array[mid] < value:
            beginIndex = mid + 1
        elif array[mid] > value:
            endIndex = mid - 1
        else: #equal
            return mid

    if array[beginIndex] == value:
        return beginIndex
    else:
        return -1
```

Test cases / output:

> ```
> print binarySearch([2,3], 0, 1, 2)
>  0
> print binarySearch([2,3], 0, 1, 3)
>  1
> print binarySearch([2,3], 0, 1, -1)
> -1
> print binarySearch([2,3,3,3,4,5], 0, 5, 3)
>  2
> ```

So it works as intended. I'm interested in feedback mostly from a functional perspective, but I'm open to anything else that might catch your eye.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Because the behaviour of the `/` operator is different.

Comment: @GregHewgill, good question. I am using Python 2.7.8, your advice is appreciated. Find any issues? Thanks.

Comment: You could `return ~beginIndex` instead of -1, so when not found, you return the ones complement of the insertion position (negative). That is what java does.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen, always nice to learn from you and I corrected indent issue and // issue you pointed out. Besides style/return method issues, do you see any functional issues in my code from a binary search tree perspective? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your function doesn't have docstrings.  Docstrings are good because they give you an opportunity to tell users of your code how to use it.  I had to read the whole code to determine that the binary search you were referring to was for element extraction on a (presumably sorted) list.
2. You don't check for (or even document) that your function only works on sorted lists.  For example `binarySearch('acb', 0, 2, 'b')` gives `-1` which might not be what users expect.  You could add an `assert array == sorted(array)` statement to guard against unsorted arrays being passed in, or at the very least mention the requirement for sortedness in the docstring.
3. You could easily supply default arguments for `beginIndex` and `endIndex` in the common use case that the search should start on the whole array.  The case of `endIndex` is a bit tricky since the default value depends on the length of the whole array.  But you could so something like:

---

```
def binarySearch(array, value, beginIndex=0, endIndex=None):
    """Docstring you need to add"""
    if endIndex is None:
        endIndex = len(array) - 1
    # rest of code
```

That way, users would not always have to supply arguments for `beginIndex` and `endIndex` if they didn't feel like it.  Notice how I had to re-order the parameter to achieve this effect, because arguments with default values must all be listed after arguments with no default (and you won't likely ever want a default value for `value`).

4. You could make the code forward-compatible with Python 3 by adding a `from __future__ import division` at the top and using `//` instead of `/`.
5. For consistency with most other regular Python functions, you might want to `raise ValueError` or something similar instead of `return -1` when the search does not succeed.  I'm only slightly joking when I say that Pythonic users might interpret a `-1` as meaning that the desired value was found at the end of the array!
6. You don't use [PEP8 style recommendations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  `binary_search()` and `begin_index` would be preferred names relative to `binarySearch()` and `beginIndex`.

Comment: F, thanks for all the comments. From functionality perspective, if I assume sorted list, any bugs? Thanks.

Comment: `//` is available even without the future import (from Python 2.2).

Comment: @JanneKarila, what is the benefit of using //? Maybe I see too many old-style code and rare see // used. Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa It behaves the same on both Python 2.x and 3.x

Comment: @holroy, thanks and always nice to learn from you and I corrected indent issue and // issue you pointed out. Besides style/return method issues, do you see any functional issues in my code from a binary search tree perspective? :)

Comment: @holroy, love your coding style in another reply which saves the work of another if/else checking. Cool. Actually I want to have one implementation which could return the matched element, or the upper bound if not match. Do you think your coding style in another post could be adopt to implement upper bound easily in case of no match (BTW, I still want to return the exact element if there is a match)?

Comment: @holroy, overall, what is the benefit of using raise error comparing to return some specific value (not limited to this question, more a general design of method question, as I see people are using both ways)? :)

Comment: @holroy, smart answer and if ValueError is raised, then the function could return value, and also could raise Exception, from the client of the function perspective, what is the right way to call the function to handle both Exception raised and normal error.